# JMeter Response data does not match the actual results

Tags: jmeter, performance, http

The HTTP Request I used in my performance testing uses JMeter's `XPath Extractor` in order to get the response data of the HTTP Request.

When the test ran, the response data for the same HTTP request is different.

What could cause this to happen?

Comment: Hi Khadija, could you please edit your question to add more details? We would need to know the actual response and the response you saved in JMeter as well as the value of your XPath Extractor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be many different reasons, it is hard to guess without seeing your Test Plan and these 2 responses.

1. Something application-specific, for instance if you are testing news portal the response will always be different as some news expire and new news are being constantly added
2. Something is wrong with your JMeter test, i.e. missing [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), missing or improperly working [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations), etc.
3. An application under test issue.